# How to keep class that extends and implements in proguard

Tags: proguard

How can i keep a class that extends FragmentActivity and implements a listener in proguard ?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying both "extends" and "implements" is not supported indeed. You could work with annotations or naming conventions, or create a common base class.